# How to check if a submodel in the model is already defined in Asp MVC view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two Class models:

**Author.cs**

```
public class Author()
{
    public int AuthorID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string  Location { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string  Bio { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}
```

**Blog.cs**

```
 public class Blog
 {
    public int BlogID { get; set; }
    public int AuthorID { get; set; }
    public virtual  Author Author { get; set; }
    [Required]

    public string  Title { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string  Description { get; set; }
 }
```

Clearly, an Author can have many Blogs
now, the problem is in the View of a Blog.
if a person writes "~/Blog/Create" I first want to check if there are already any Author Objects.
if not, I will redirect them to the "~/Author/Create" first.
that's what I have tried to accomplish thus far:

the header of **Blog/Create.cshtml**:

```
@model MVCproject.Models.Blog

@{
  if (Model.Author == null)
  {

        Response.Redirect("~/Author/Create");

  }
```

That's the most logical way I can express it, yet the Null Exception is thrown at me, and I don't know to get around this problem.
I suspect I have to change "if(Model.Author == null) " statement to something more convenient.

**EDIT:**

I haven't changed anything in the controller, I left the mvc scaffolding as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bad design decision to have any logic in the view. You should perform the redirect in your controller instead.

In your create blog action, if the author is `null` just redirect the user to another action:

```
return RedirectToAction("Create", "Author");
```

Comment: Worked Great! No logic in Views, got it,
[ScreenShot](http://imgdetop.com/img-548ac4062c977.html)
what would I do without an angel programmer who's watching over!
 Thank you so Much!

Comment: @Adamotto can you post the code of your controller?